# Рассылка почты

Tags: email, php

Такой вопрос: есть стандартный набор - бд с юзерами, поле email, надо сделать рассылку по базе 3000 юзеров.

Дедовский метод - выборка, цикл, отправка мыла.

Интересно, каким образом можно по другому реализовать рассылку, не заставляя отправителя ждать пол часа пока все 3к записей пройдут?

В phpbb, например, точно по-другому реализовано, проверял: 3к юзеров, делаешь рассылку - 1 секунда и письма ушли.

Может они как то передают сразу в очередь на сервер или как?
Спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, в случае phpbb графа "получатель" отображается как unclosed_recipients

Comment: Апаю вопрос, очень актуально. Неужели на такой простой вопрос не найдется ни одного умника?

Comment: >Кстати, в случае phpbb графа "получатель" отображается как unclosed_recipients

Ну если настройки указаны криво, то да. Оно и в коде видно:
<pre><code>$mail_to = ($to == '') ? 'undisclosed-recipients:;' : $to;</code></pre>

А вообще, если так хочется "Как в phpbb", то что мешает раскопать его код? Тем более, что все функции отправки писем лежат в файле functions_messenger.php

Comment: Копал, но толи "кони не едут", толи я уставший..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак ответ найден.

Используем последнюю версию class.phpmailer

> require 'class.phpmailer.php';
>
> $mail = new PHPMailer();
>
> $mail->From = 'my@mail.ru';      // from (email)
>
> $mail->FromName ='my name';   // from name
>
> $mail->AddAddress('my@mail.ru', 'my name');// шлем письмо себе
>
> $sql=mysql_query("SELECT email,name FROM users WHERE 1 $add");
>
> while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
>
> {
>
> $mail->AddBCC($row['email'], $row['name']); // добавить скрытую копию, в цикле добавятся все адреса из бд
>
> }
>
> $mail->IsHTML(true);        // HTML format
>
> $mail->Subject = $_POST['subj'];  // subject
>
> $mail->Body = $_POST['mail']; // message
>
> $mail->Send(); // отправляем
>
> $mail->ClearBCCs(); // очищаем список адресов

Есть одна проблема, думаю, со временем разберусь: когда мейлеру попадается несуществующий адрес, он громогласно об этом заявляет не стесняясь прямо там где отрабатывает :) чуток надо покопать класс, и, думаю, проблема уйдет.

Answer (score 0):

1 письмо можно отправить сразу 100 адресатам. слепые копии называется. вроде как быстрей должно отправлятся

Comment: как реализовать?

Comment: добавляешь в заголовок письма поле Bcc и там еще один цикл куда пихаешь 100 адресов. Сам пытался реализовать в итоге забросил так как Php на начальной стадии так сказать. запутался с этими двумя циклами...

Comment: Хотел бы услышать еще другие методы. Мне почему-то сильно кажется, что есть способ получше =)

Comment: я задавал аналогичный вопрос ответа нормального так и не дождался) может тут буду ждать вместе с вами)

Answer (score 0):

[@Ozim](/users/2690/ozim), мой тебе совет. Посмотри как устроен Zend_Mail. И вообще, если что-то не знаешь - смотри как делают в ZF. Они плохо не сделают. а копаться во всяких phpbb, drupal и прочем - жизни не хватит.